# How to move multiple messages in mutt

Tags: email, message, command-line-interface, mutt

Before all of my messages were in one maildir. Now I want move all arch-general mail to another one.

From [here](http://wiki.mutt.org/?MuttFaq/Action), I see:

```
"move" as we know it from other places is "save" in mutt. 
"save" as we know it from other places is "copy" in mutt.

~e EXPR         message which contains EXPR in the ``Sender'' field
```

so I use pattern in index

```
'T'  and  '~e arch-general' then  's'
```

but just one message moved.

How can I move all pattterned messages to another dir?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`;s`

```
;     tag-prefix     apply next function to tagged messages
```

Comment: As with several key-bindings in mutt, this one seems to be mode-specific. (A list of mutt modes is available [here](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/wikis/MuttGuide/Actions).) It works in index mode, but if you attempt to use it in pager mode, mutt will respond with the error message, `Key is not bound.  Press '?' for help.` This is true even if the index is showing, e.g. if you have a line like `set pager_index_lines=8` in your `.muttrc`.